# Is there anyway to customize number keyboard for iOS (not iOS 8)?

Tags: ios, keyboard

I need to customize iOS's native number keyboard for entering PIN in iOS 7 and earlier.

The requirement is: Numbers on keyboard should be random position each time the keyboard display.

[image: The numbers should be display randomly]

So I cannot use the Phone keyboard of iOS.

Is there any native way to do this (without creating a fake keyboard)?

Thank you so much

Comment: no there isn't, either you use iOS 8, a keyboard made by yourself, or the numeric keyboard (which isn't random)

Comment: thank you! so, the only solution is: making a fake keyboard?

Comment: yes, it it isn't that hard anyways